# If I reset the Windows Firewall with netsh will programs re-prompt for access?

Tags: windows-firewall, netsh

If I run the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

The windows firewall will get flushed back to it's defaults and looses any program specific rules.

Will programs that require firewall access start prompting the user after the reset is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as when a program prompts for access, it sets a rule.